# Set list of arrays from a variable - BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, sed

It's a simple thing I'm sure, just with the right combination.

I have a file with a list of prepared arrays.  I modify them using sed reading them all into a variable.  I then need to set them as part of a script.

Original reference file:

```
var1=( "1" "%%" )
var2=( "2" "%%" )
```

I do my stuff with it so it becomes:

```
var1=( "1" "3" )
var2=( "2" "4" )
```

...and the list of modified arrays is all stored in a variable.  I need to then read that list of arrays into a script.

Comment: Errrr and what's the exact question?

Comment: Sorry ;) The question, is how would I set that list of variables in my script.  I tried various ways using set, export etc, but they get quoted as strings not arrays etc.

Comment: You can just copy the list into the bash script..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try eval:

```
$ x="a=asdf"; eval $x ;  echo $a
```

outputs: `asdf`

Comment: Like I said, something simple! D'oh.